# Where to download Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook for C# or an alternative way

Tags: c#, email, outlook-2013

I'm trying to build a program where it reads in my outlook emails from work and I've been digging around and seen a lot of people using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.

However, I don't have Outlook on the machine I'm developing this program so I was wondering if anyone know or could tell me where I can actually just download and install this Interop for Outlook. I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find anything useful except "Buy Outlook".

### Edit

If buying Outlook is the only way, is there another alternative solution to approach this?

Comment: Buy Outlook. You can't do any testing without Outlook installed anyway, all that Office Interop does is talk to the installed Office application through COM.

Comment: Sorry - maybe I should of said I'm using Citrix that connects to my work place PC so I can test it by copy and pasting the software to it, which is annoying, but better than nothing :)